# Xamarin - Acessando API que retorna JSON

Tags: json, api, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

Seguinte, sou MUITO novo nessa questão de API. 
Criei minha primeira web application .net Framework 4.5.2. 
Criei ela bem padrão mesmo(conforme VS 2015), e criei um controller para teste "TesteController.cs", testei ela localmente e funciona, subi para um host, e funciona também (http://www.afectus.com.br/api/teste/0).
Segue o método GET da minha API

> ```
> public string Get(int id)
>     {
>         ClassRetorno cr = new ClassRetorno();
>         cr.Id = 1;
>         cr.Nome = "BraKa Yedmore";
>         cr.Email = "braka@braka.com";
>         JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
>         string output = ser.Serialize(cr);
>         return output;
>     }
> ```

Minha intenção é que, ao tocar no botão, seja exibido um Alert com essas informações(lidas do retorno da API).
Segue o método executado ao toque no botão:

> ```
> private async void buttonConnect_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         ClassRetorno cr = await GetData();
>         string retorno = "Id: " + cr.Id + ";\nNome: " + cr.Nome + ";\nE-Mail: " + cr.Email;
>         await DisplayAlert("Alert", retorno, "Ok");
>     }
> ```

Segue o método GetData

> ```
> public async Task<ClassRetorno> GetData()
>     {
>         using (var client = new HttpClient())
>         {
>             var response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.afectus.com.br/api/teste/0");
>             if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
>             {
>                 var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
>                 //string contentTest = "{\"id\":1,\"nome\":\"BraKa Yedmore\",\"email\":\"braka@braka.com\"}";
>                 ClassRetorno cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassRetorno>(content);
>                 return cr;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 return null;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Fiz um teste com a string *contentTest* apenas para saber se funciona. E funciona!
No entanto não funciona quando populo *content* com retorno da API.
Este é o conteúdo de *content* retornado da API

> ```
> string content = "\"{\\\"Id\\\":1,\\\"Nome\\\":\\\"BraKa Yedmore\\\",\\\"Email\\\":\\\"braka@braka.com\\\"}\"";
> ```

E esta é a Exception apresentada na tentativa de deserializar *content*

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "{"Id":1,"Nome":"BraKa Yedmore","Email":"braka@braka.com"}" to type 'MobileApp.ClassRetorno'. Path '', line 1, position 69.

E esta é a classe *ClassRetorno.cs*

> ```
> public class ClassRetorno
> {
>     private int id;
>     private string nome;
>     private string email;
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Nome { get; set; }
>     public string Email { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Sei que ficou um tanto quanto extensa minha dúvida, mas tentei passar todas as informações possíveis. Se alguem souber e puder me ajudar ou orientar-me como resolver este problema. 
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o problema
Eu estava tentando usar o *JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content)* diretamente da resposta que eu recebia da API.
Para resolver, eu tive que *deserializar* sem definir um tipo, e depois *deserializar* definindo o tipo

> ```
> if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
>             {
>                 var retorno = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
>                 object content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(retorno);
>                 ClassRetorno cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassRetorno>(content.ToString());
>                 return cr;
>             }
> ```

Obrigado!